# Can listeners be added to objects without a reference name?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

I have the following GUI:

[image]

As you can see, the panels with green and yellow borders have all the same format. 2 labels and a button. I have created them using the following function which I call on other function using a `for` clause to create several of those panels:

```
private JPanel subject (int id, String name, int credits, boolean optional) {
        JPanel main = new JPanel();

        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        if (optional) {
            main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 1), "("+id+")"));
        } else {
            main.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 1), "("+id+")"));
        }

        JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
        namePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        namePanel.add(new JLabel(name));

        JPanel creditsPanel = new JPanel();
        creditsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        creditsPanel.add(new JLabel(credits + " credits"));

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Add to favorites"));   //Here I add the button to the main panel


        main.add(namePanel);
        main.add(creditsPanel);
        main.add(buttonPanel);

        return main;    //I return the panel to add it to the frame
    }
```

The `JButtons` in the panels are being created but not assigned to a name.

How can I add a action listener for every button on each panel that is created?

Should I create a reference name for the button in the function in order to make this?

Please note that all the buttons do similar things but not the exact same thing.

Comment: If you want to add a listener to your button, then creating it anonymously is probably not the way to go. **Or**, create a factory method to create your `JButton` instances and pass the `Listener` to the factory (along with the button label).

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to do is have to create a class member or a local member that is initialized and then assign a listener to that specific button. Alternatively you can create a function that adds a button to a panel and assigns some listener to it.